# Differentiation of a natural log with fraction of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I am starting with differenciation and I stumbled upon the following exercise:
Find $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$, where
$$f(x)=\ln \left({\cos x + \sin x \over \cos x - \sin x}\right).$$
So I applied the chain rule and quotient rules as it is a compound differentiation:
$$\frac{d\ln f(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{f(x)} \frac{df(x)}{dx}.$$

This results in a very large equation, specially when applying the quotient rule:
$${(\cos x - \sin x) \over (\cos x + \sin x)} \cdot {(-\sin x + \cos x)(\cos x - \sin x) - (\cos x + \sin x)(-\sin x - \cos x) \over (\cos x - \sin x)^2}$$

I am not sure if I am doing this well. I would like to not be this specific so this question could help others, but I am really struggling to solve this differenciation but I am unable to do it. Any tip?

Comment: Hi Raj, welcome to Math on Stack Exchange. I reformatted your equations for you; note that you can get full-size equations using $$ instead of $, and to get properly formatted functions use e.g. \cos, \sin, and \ln instead of cos, sin and ln.

Comment: Thank you Douglas! I saw it was looking tiny but I thought that was the standard way.

Comment: Your large expression simplifies down drastically if you continue with it. You will run into nearly the same large expression using the method in the answer, if you try to combine the fractions after differentiation. Splitting logs is still a very useful method though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you can eliminate the quotient rule by using

$$\ln{(a/b)} = \ln{a} - \ln{b}$$

Now you have

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln{\left(\frac{\cos{x}+\sin{x}}{\cos{x}-\sin{x}} \right )} = \frac{d}{dx} \ln{(\cos{x}+\sin{x})} - \frac{d}{dx}\ln{(\cos{x}-\sin{x})}$$

Now use the chain rule.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I would be able to solve it now - however, I would never be able to use that formula since it does not exist in any formula table, or at least not in mine. I never heard about this one. Is there any name for those "trick" formulas?

Comment: @Raj: it is a fundamental property of a logarithm.  If you do not know it, then you should review the properties of logarithms.  Also, if this solution was useful to you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Okay, understood. It was useful indeed, thank you!